# How to speed up AI platform training job queues?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

Whenever I submit a training job to the AI platform, I have to wait around 5-10 minutes for my training job to start after it is queued. This happens when I submit a package for training as well as when I submit a docker image.

The logs go something like:

```
T0:        "Job creation request has been successfully validated."
T0 + 1s:   "Waiting for job to be provisioned."
T0 + 1s:   "Job trainer_20200612_121714 is queued."
T0 + 3s:   "Waiting for training program to start."

T0 + 7min:  My training job finally starts
```

Is this completely on Google's side? Are there any settings on my end that can affect this?

Comment: what do you mean by " 5-10 minutes after provisioning"? What do you see on the log, or on the screen for deducing this?

Comment: Hi. I added the logs to my question. When I said provisioned I actually meant queued. Updated this also

Comment: What command line do you use? Do you request special hardware for your training?

Comment: In this case I just used `gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME --region $REGION --master-image-uri $IMAGE_URI`. No config.yaml

Comment: I guess it's normal. When I run a training without container, directly in python/Tensorflow, it take 2 minutes for starting the training. It's maybe longer for training jobs with container image.